# Add row in result set of Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying achieve below
eg.

this is what I have ...

```
  Name     Amount
  AAA        15
  AAA        20
  CCC        30
  CCC        50
```

this is what I want

```
  Name     Amount
  AAA        15
  AAA        20
             35     --(want to insert row which display sum of 1st & 2nd rows)
  CCC        30
  CCC        50 
             80      --(want to insert row which display sum of 3rd & 4th rows)
```

Comment: That is a formatting issue. Do it in the program logic and not in SQL

Comment: SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the first two rows unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: is it fix for 2 rows ? or it can be more then that ?

Comment: @juergend then can you provide programming logic in c# ?

Comment: No. Do it yourself. If you get stuck then post the C# code you tried with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: @Husen no ! it will be multiple

Comment: @PrasadZagade - What is the order to sum the records ? Should the sum should happen for every two records ?

Comment: Is it that you want the `SUM` of the ones that have the same `Name`?

Comment: @PrasadZagade Members of this site are not your personal workforce. You are expected to do your own work. If you have anything you are stuck on, then post a question here with a simplified version of your code that reproduces your issue and we can then help. Please read through the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site for a good rundown on what is expected of you when asking a question.

Comment: @Prdp Yes ! sum should happen for every two records.

Comment: What in your table identifies that particular rows should be added together? Do you have another column that groups records, or is it just every two columns in a sequence? The latter seems too arbitrary to be of any use. If you do not have a field that is used for sum grouping, then you should really think about adding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a summary of rows by name, you could use a union, and a group by, and an order by:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Name char(3), Amount int)

insert @tbl
VALUES 
 ('AAA',15)
,('AAA',20)
,('CCC',30)
,('CCC',50)


select Name, Amount
FROM @tbl

UNION ALL

SELECT Name, SUM(Amount)
FROM @tbl GROUP BY Name

ORDER BY Name
```

For a working example using subquery and CTE (only used as an example replacement for the actual table), take the following:

```
with vals as
(
    select 'aaa' as Name, 15 as Amount
    union all
    select 'aaa' as Name, 10 as Amount
    union all
    select 'bbb' as Name, 20 as Amount
    union all
    select 'bbb' as Name, 30 as Amount
    union all
    select 'bbb' as Name, 50 as Amount
)
select *
from
(
    select 'Amount' as ValType, Name, Amount
    from vals
    union all
    select 'Total' as ValType, Name, sum(Amount)
    from vals
    group by Name
)
order by Name, ValType
;
```

This will group by the `Name` column, and sum within a subquery, then sort the output using manually added `ValType` identifier column.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer to expand upon it? My answer is pretty much just an extension/clarification of yours, so I don't feel it warrants a new answer. You can always reject my edit if you feel it doesn't add to it.

Comment: No problem, go for it

Comment: Not really sure I see how a CTE helps besides as a way of getting some temporary values in there - the question seems to indicate the values are actually coming from a table

Comment: It was mostly just for a self-contained working example. Yes, the eventual working code would be modified using the posters actual tables. I moved the CTE outside of the actual query to avoid confusion.

Comment: thank you very much @DanField . It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using UNION

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('AAA',15),
                      ('AAA',20),
                      ('CCC',30),
                      ('CCC',50)) CT (NAME,AMOUNT)


UNION ALL

SELECT NAME+' '+ 'Total' as Tot ,SUM(AMOUNT) FROM (VALUES ('AAA',15),
                      ('AAA',20),
                      ('CCC',30),
                      ('CCC',50)) CT (NAME,AMOUNT)                      
GROUP BY NAME+' '+ 'Total') X
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest doing 2 **selects** and then use **union all** to join them

```
Select name, amount from table
union all
select '' as total, sum(amount) from table
```

Comment: No, this simply sums all records into a single aggregate value. It does not sum based off of any type of grouping, which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @gmiley, the idea is not to provide a completed answer, but show how the problem could be solved. By using 2 **select** with **union all** is totally possible to solve it.